# My mute command doesn't remove the roles properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

does anyone know if I have to use a database for a mute command now or what since if a member already has a role that lets them able to talk the muted role has no affect even regardless of the role hierarchy I made it where when I mute the member it takes all the roles away which works but when the time runs out or they get unmuted the member cant get their roles back anyone know how to deal with this?

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member=None, time=None, *, reason= None): 
    if time== None:
        await ctx.send("you gotta set a duration.")
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedrole=discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="muted")
    time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}
    tempmute= int(time[:-1]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
    roles = [role for role in member.roles]
    
    if not mutedrole:
        mutedrole=await guild.create_role(name="muted", permissions=discord.Permissions(send_messages=False))

    if reason== None:
        reason= "No reason"

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedrole, speak=False, send_messages=False, add_reactions=False)

    await member.edit(roles=[])
    await member.add_roles(mutedrole, reason=reason)
    embed= discord.Embed(description=f"**{member}** was muted for: {reason}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    embed= discord.Embed(description= f"You were muted in **{guild}** for: {reason}\n"
    "\n **Tip**: don't be useless man!", color=0x000000)
    await member.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
    await member.remove_roles(mutedrole)
    await member.add_roles(roles)
```

Comment: Do you still need the Mute role now that Discord has built in "timeout" capability?

Answer (score 0):

`add_roles()` has a parameter called `*roles` which is an **argument list** of `abc.SnowFlake` representing a `discord.Role`. Means when you have multiple roles, add a `*` right before `roles` like that (**same for `remove_roles`**):

```
await member.add_roles(*roles)
```

**BUT** this doesn't work yet, since `member.roles` includes also the `@everyone` "role" which can't be added to a user (it's the default role). You need to remove it from the list.

##### The end result

```
roles = member.roles[1:]  # discord.Member has an attribute roles
...

await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
await member.remove_roles(mutedrole)
await member.add_roles(*roles)
```

---

###### References:

- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?discord%20member#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [`Member.remove_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?discord%20member#discord.Member.remove_roles)